# Pandas Groupby if datetime within 30 minutes of each other

Tags: python, pandas, time, pandas-groupby

Hi I was wondering whether anyone is able to help with the below question.

In the below table, I want to group the data by location, TV and datetime if datetime is within 30 minutes of each other and assigned a group number to it. If the location and TV is the same but their timestamps are not within 30 minutes of each other, they should be assigned a different group number. Example table below

```
location    TV      datetime

UK     bake off    29/10/2021 21:20:00

UK     bake off    29/10/2021 21:20:00

UK     bake off    29/10/2021 21:40:00

UK     masterchef  29/10/2021 22:47:00

UK     masterchef  29/10/2021 23:05:00


The  result I want is the below


location    TV      datetime           group

UK     bake off    29/10/2021 21:20:00  1

UK     bake off    29/10/2021 21:20:00  1

UK     bake off    29/10/2021 21:40:00  1

UK     masterchef  29/10/2021 22:47:00  2

UK     masterchef  29/10/2021 23:05:00  2
```

**The result I get with pd.Grouper is the below**. However, as pd.Grouper takes equally spaced time intervals, it groups the 3rd and 5th row in separate groups as per below.

```
location    TV     datetime           group

UK     bake off    29/10/2021 21:20:00  1

UK     bake off    29/10/2021 21:20:00  1

UK     bake off    29/10/2021 21:40:00  2

UK     masterchef  29/10/2021 22:47:00  3

UK     masterchef  29/10/2021 23:05:00  4
```

I'm using the following code:

```
df['group'] = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key = 'datetime', freq = '30min'), 'location', 'TV']).ngroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.  It uses the minimum time for each (location, TV pair).  First, set up the data:

```
import pandas as pd

# create data, with a new row
data = [
    ('location', 'TV',      'datetime'),
    ('UK', 'bake off',    '29/10/2021 21:20:00'),
    ('UK', 'bake off',    '29/10/2021 21:20:00'),
    ('UK', 'bake off',    '29/10/2021 21:40:00'),
    ('UK', 'bake off',    '29/10/2021 23:59:59'),  # new
    ('UK', 'masterchef',  '29/10/2021 22:47:00'),
    ('UK', 'masterchef',  '29/10/2021 23:05:00'),
]
```

Then, perform the calculations:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data[1:], columns = data[0])

# convert to datetime
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

# find min time for each (location, TV) pair
df['start'] = df.groupby(['location', 'TV'])['datetime'].transform('min')

# subtract min time, then integer division in 30-minute intervals
df['elapsed'] = (df['datetime'] - df['start']).dt.seconds // (30 * 60)

# assign group numbers
df['group'] = df.groupby(['location', 'TV', 'elapsed']).ngroup()
print(df)
```

Finally, look at the results:

```
  location          TV            datetime               start  elapsed  group
0       UK    bake off 2021-10-29 21:20:00 2021-10-29 21:20:00        0      0
1       UK    bake off 2021-10-29 21:20:00 2021-10-29 21:20:00        0      0
2       UK    bake off 2021-10-29 21:40:00 2021-10-29 21:20:00        0      0
3       UK    bake off 2021-10-29 23:59:59 2021-10-29 21:20:00        5      1
4       UK  masterchef 2021-10-29 22:47:00 2021-10-29 22:47:00        0      2
5       UK  masterchef 2021-10-29 23:05:00 2021-10-29 22:47:00        0      2
```